# String greater than (>) operator in PowerBuilder

Tags: string, operators, powerbuilder

I'm wondering if anyone can tell me what the following line of code would actually do.  I'm not a PowerBuilder developer, but I'm trying to recreate a piece of software in a modern language, and just want to know what this line does exactly.

```
var_1 = ' ';
var_2 = ' ';
var_3 = ' ';

....
//some logic that might change var_1, var_2, or var_3
....

var_all = var_1 + var_2 + var_3
if trim(var_all) > "    " and trim(var_all) > "" then //that's 4 spaces
    //some logic
end if
```

I have a feeling this is checking length, but can't find out for sure what that > operator does with strings in PowerBuilder.

I think what is supposed to happen is if the total length of the `var_all` string is greater than 4, do `//some logic`, but I can't be sure.

Comment: Have you even looked at the help which comes with PowerBuilder?

Comment: I have been looking at the online documentation, but couldn't find much about comparing strings.  I will look at the help within powerbuilder to see if that has anything more concrete.

Comment: Yep - the online documentation is the same.  I assure you, I would have posted the same question, as it isn't explicit about what would happen exactly in this case, but the accepted answer seems to make the most sense.  Do you have other documentation you would like to share?

Comment: One more comment- the logic adding var1, 2 and 3, in PowerBuilder if any of the three happen to be null, than var_all will be null because you cannot add null to non-null. Just wanted to make sure you had all bases covered, you often have to consider nulls in PowerBuilder.

Comment: Thanks @RichBianco. He did actually make sure they were not null earlier. Thankfully I am not modifying this. I'm converting the software to a Java library instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: String operators <, >, and = do a case-sensitive alphabetical comparison of two strings based on your current *regional settings*.

EX: *Regional settings* = Danish sorting => 'AA' sorts **after** 'Z' ('AA' equivalent to 'Å')

---

- `Trim(var_all)` removes *all* leading and trailing spaces (but only ASCII space = ASCII value 0x20)
- `... > ""` implements "*any non-empty string*"
- `... > "    "` implements "*any string sorting **after** a space character*"

  - Examples of leading character that sorts **before** space character: Escape, Form-Feed, Carriage-Return, Line-Feed, and Tab

In your context equivalent behaviour can be obtained in PowerScript as follows:

```
IF Trim(var_all) > " " THEN
   ...
END IF
```

Comment: Good point on the special characters that sort before space, I hadn't thought of that at first.

Comment: @MicKr- - I did test this and have confirmed that this is what the is happening.  Also, trim(var_all) > " " is all that is needed.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You are going to change it to a modern language ... hahaha ... I explain: Trim () removes spaces on both sides of a string, any blank string does not meet the condition to enter the if, but if var_all for example is : Var_all = "1" meets and enters the if. You are actually verifying that var_all has a value that is not a target.

Comment: Ok, so as long as var_all isn't an empty string of spaces, it will enter the if?

Comment: Also, I modified the question slightly and added a condition. I forgot to include that he's also checking for `and trim(var_all) > ""`. Are both statements needed? Would trim just remove one space from the beginning and end?  I did look up the trim method, and I believe this is the case, but that trim(var_all) > "    " is making me scratch my head.  If a string with 2 spaces is passed in, would this enter the if? What if it had 8 spaces? There's another line that includes 5 strings concatenated, with defaults as mentioned above.  There may be some with more strings.

Comment: I just tested it by creating my own test application. I'm not sure why I didn't do that yesterday. Either way, all that is needed, as far as I can tell from my tests, is trim(var_all) > "", because trim removes all spaces from beginning and end, from what I can tell.  I'm not sure why the old developer had the greater than "    " (with spaces), as it seems the second condition catches anything the first would.

Comment: @adpro, correct you just want to make sure the string has something in it besides spaces. Anything other than spaces should perform the logic inside the if statement.

Comment: @adpro - no the original developer did not need to code it that way only one condition need be checked, does the variable, after trimming left and right spaces have a value in it. I think you've got it!

Comment: @RichBianco - I think the accepted answer is what is going on. If the string starts with a value that is considered "greater" than a space, then it will fail.  (or less than -- I can't remember).  Either way, I think he's checking if it is blank and contains valid text.  I think he wants to ignore something like "~" being the string.  I'm going to test and I'll verify.

Comment: @RichBianco - I tested this with using "-" as the string. If I only use trim("-") > "", it will return true and enter the if.  If I use trim("-") > " ", it will return false and not enter the if.  So, I need the space in there for sorting, as the accepted answer explains. It looks like the developer did want to check that the string is starting with anything sorted greater than a space. Thanks for the input! I'll have to figure out how to handle this in Java, if I even need to.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length of var_all buy using the following code:
`var_1`, `var_2`, `var_3` are declared with 1 space and with the function `trim()` will removed all spaces.

```
if len(trim(var_all)) > 0 then 
    //some logic
end if
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm not looking for how to check the length, or to modify the code.  Please re-read.  I am trying to figure out what the above code does exactly.

Comment: Even so, this solution will accomplish the same thing as your original code.  Trim removes spaces so an empty string in your variable or spaces in your variable will not match both sides of the AND. The programmer that wrote your original code was obviously confused. I would have written it like If Not Isnull( var_name) and Len( Trim( var_name ) ) > 0 then - do your logic. The first part covers null, sometimes when comparing nulls you get unexpected results. fwiw

Comment: @RichBianco, you're neglecting the sorting and ignoring of strings that start with "-", for example. This answer doesn't address that portion of it, so it is not equal. It looks like the previous developer wanted to make sure strings that start with characters prior to the space, when sorted, are ignored. Also, as stated a few times, it doesn't matter what you would have done. This code is not being edited or maintained. It is being re-written in another language, so I only need to know what it does, not how it should have been written. This answer doesn't address my original question.

Answer (score -2):

The use of less than and greater than with strings isn't normal. It will always return false. To compare string length you have to use the Len function.

Comment: It will not always return false.

Comment: If true, it is an undocumented feature. Please explain how.

Comment: My code proceeds into the scope of the condition, so yes, it can return true. Also, look at the accepted answer.  Also, try it out yourself.  I did, and it definitely returns true sometimes.

Comment: And as we have figured out with this, since I was asking what the code was doing, and suspected it was looking at length, this is actually returning false for any string that starts with a character that exists, in the way strings are sorted in PowerBuilder, prior to the space.  So, if I put in something like "!" for the string, it will return false.  But, "yep, this is valid" would return true.  I haven't confirmed 100%, but it seems to be the case. Either way, it will return true, and it isn't just looking at length.

Comment: Interesting and makes sense but because the official documentation doesn't cover this scenario, the developer shouldn't​ have coded it that way and their intent isn't clear.

Comment: It actually is kind of documented, in a roundabout way. See bit.ly/2rBafMR - Also, this code was originally written 20 years ago or so.  I could go on and on about how it should have been written and the lack of clearness of code. When you deal with old code, sometimes it's not clear, and sometimes it makes you scratch your head. It is, however, dangerous to assert something as absolute when you do not know, which is the case with your answer.

Comment: You call Java a modern language? Very funny!

Comment: How is it not a modern programming language?

Comment: I thought I would explain why I think it is a modern language. It's OOP. It's Managed, updated currently, and used in old and new applications. It's one of the most popular, and is used in modern learning and development. So, yes, Java is 22 years old, but that's young compared to a lot of modern languages. Modern does not have to equal new either. A language that continues to grow and develop can be modern. If Lambda's weren't included, or other modern language constructs, then I would be inclined to agree with you, but I do not agree with your statement, again.